# Unable to remove html tags from response JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

Hi I am new to AngularJS. I am having a problem parsing JSON data to proper format. Actually the JSON response itself returned HTML format data (it contains HTML tags like &lt,;BR,> etc). If I check the response in browser it returns fine, but in device(TAB,MOBILE) the HTML tags are also getting appended. I am using AngularJS to bind the JSON response to DOM. Is there any way to simply ignore HTML tags in JQuery or in AngularJs? At the same time I don't want to remove the HTML tags as they are necessary to define "new line", "space", "table tag" etc.

A sample response I am getting is like:

```
A heavier weight, stretchy, wrinkle resistant fabric.&lt;BR&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Fabric Content:&lt;BR&gt;100% Polyester&lt;BR&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Wash Care:&lt;BR&gt;
```

If I apply the binding using `{{pdp.desc}}`, the HTML tags are also getting added. Is there any way to accomplish this?

I have added ng-bind-html-unsafe="pdp.desc", but still "BR" tags r coming.

Comment: Why are you sending tags?

Comment: Its coming from service  and I cant change it. Have to modify from front-end.

Comment: you can always create a new Element with `document.createElement()`, add the HTML content to it, then call `element.innerText()` to get just the text...

Answer (score 2):

useless html tags can be remove using regix expression, try this

```
str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')
```

Comment: Using a regular expression to parse HTML is fraught with pitfalls. HTML is not a regular language and hence can't be 100% correctly parsed with a regex. This is just one of many problems you will run into. The best approach is to use an HTML / XML parser to do this for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Try to use three pairs of brackets {{{pdp.desc}}} In Handlebars it works, possible in your case to.

Comment: Its giving Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS HTML parser

```
var pattern = @"<(img|a)[^>]*>(?<content>[^<]*)<";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var m = regex.Match(sSummary);
if ( m.Success ) { 
  sResult = m.Groups["content"].Value;
```

courtesy stackoverflow.