# How do I remove an element but not its content with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which is a simple `<a>` element.

```
var str = '<a href="somewhere.com">Link</a>'
```

Which I want to turn into:

```
Link
```

I can remove the `</a>` part easily with `str.replace("</a>", "")`but how would I remove the opening tag `<a href="somewhere.com>`?

Comment: If you are dealing with Javascript Strings and not DOM elements you should use a Regular Expression. See the following Question for more information on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will strip the whole tag:

```
str.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'');
```

And this just the first part:

```
str.replace(/<[^/>]+>/g, '');
```

Comment: The i flag (case insensitivity flag) is not necessary. The parenthesis are also not necessary. While not applicable if the content is in fact "Link", occurances of /<[^>]+>/g in the content will be removed.

Answer (score 8):

Use `unwrap` like

```
$('a').contents().unwrap();
```

But it work with the elements that are related to DOM.For your **Better** solution try like

```
 str = ($(str).text());
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NATnr/43/)

Comment: The OP shows an example of using a javascript string variable, not a DOM element. This solution would not work unless he added it to the DOM first.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery, you can do it on the fly as follows

```
$('<a href="somewhere.com">Link</a>').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    var str = '<a href="somewhere.com">Link</a>';       
    alert($(str).text());
```