# Removing <div class> code blocks from a text file

Tags: html

I have extracted some information from an .html file and put it into a text file.
The information is there, but once in a while i have something like this coming up:

```
info, info...
info, info...

    <div class="ratings-link"> <img alt="arrows" class="icon" src= bla bla...</a></div>"

info, info...
info, info...
```

What i want to do is basically remove everything which is not info. 
(Getting rid of:

```
<div class="ratings-link" ....bla bla... </a></div>
```

all together.

What is the best way/tool to achieve this? I wrote a C program with scanf but it
wouldn't work since not all these divs has same end string. But they all share
same mentioned pattern.

Comment: Do you want to delete them from the file altogether or just hide them from the browser?

Comment: You want to use a String Class Replace function usually available in mostly languages like in C++ it is string::replace.

Comment: maybe instead of reading the html as text, you could parse it as html file and only extract text without elements? this can be done in a variety of tools, like CKEditor for javascript, or HtmlAguilityPack in c#, im sure there are more for other languages. you could also use RegEx to find tags with and without closings and delete them

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: I would suggest Node.js (CLI?) and a DOM parser to get the text content, or remove dom nodes altogether (depending on if you want the text from within the `<a>` tag to stay). See https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Answer (score 1):

If this were me I would write a quick script in either PHP or Python to do this.

PHP has the strip_tags function:
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Python has a library called beautiful soup which is very mature and great for this kind of thing:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Or how about any language that has Regex support removing all that match <[^>]*>

Answer (score 0):

you can use RegEx in almost any programming language in order to filter your text and remove unneeded information.

in your case, the relevant regex would be: `<[^>]*>`

and here is an example in c#:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Program
{
    static string myString =  "info, info..." + 
    Environment.NewLine + "info, info..." + 
    Environment.NewLine + "<div class='ratings-link'> <img alt='arrows' class='icon' src= bla bla...</a></div>" + 
    Environment.NewLine + "info, info..." + 
    Environment.NewLine + "info, info...";
    public static void Main()
    {
        String result = Regex.Replace(myString, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Live Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OQsbNd)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually trying to do, is stripping any html tags from your text. The simplest way to occasionally strip tags via copy and paste is to use an online tool like http://www.striphtml.com/ or maybe even more convenient http://www.zubrag.com/tools/html-tags-stripper.php which offers the alternative of entering a url to strip from (makes extracting text first obsolete) and lets you choose tags you may want to exclude.

If i misunderstood you, and it is your intention to write some html stripper program, well, every language/platform that i know of has functions, that achieve exactly that. PHP f.e. has the `strip_tags()` function.