# remove HTML tags from cshtml webpage in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have following controller

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View(db.AB_Product_vs_Field.ToList());
    }
```

I'm getting following view for above controller method which is containing with HTML tags(actually those field's values are saved in database with HTML tags)

[image]

How can I remove these html tags and show just the plain text.what's the least and simple effort for this

Comment: @Arvaan But it might also open up for script injection!

Comment: Ok. My bad. He just wants to remove tags. I was thinking he wants to apply HTML tags effect also

Comment: Send the view to simulate it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display only "Product Title" in the 3rd column?

Comment: The best way to handle this is to *not* save the HTML-code in the database. Is that possible for you?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yep , remove all the HTML tag just show plain text

Comment: Using a regex in the controller would probably be easiest.

Comment: @StephenMuecke any example for that

Comment: Have a look at [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags), but there are plenty of other examples on SO

Answer (score 1):

Simply make use of @Html.Raw() that returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

Comment: I think it will also give effect of HTML Tag, and he does't want it. He just want to remove HTML tags and want specific Text decorated by tag

Answer (score 1):

This will remove html tags

```
@Regex.Replace(your_variable, @"<[^>]+>", "")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: where should I place this ?

Comment: into your view or controller, its depend on your code

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` is the best option to do it.

Let us example:-

If you want to remove any HTML tags:-

```
String OnlyString = someString.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

If you want to remove any specific HTML tag:-

```
String removedSpecific = someString.replaceAll("(?i)&lt;td[^>]*>", "");
```

Hope above example will solve your issue. :)

Comment: could you please let me know where should I insert this ? controller method or viewpage ?

Comment: It's a C# code, you can add this in controller, if you want same conversion in view, Please make some ajax like call, and from javascript you can . :)