# Remove HTML tags from output Python

Tags: python, html

I'm working in Python 2, and I have the following script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

page = "http://hidden.com/example"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Craig'}
html = requests.post(page, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

final = soup.find('p',{'class':'text'})

print final
```

This works on a website which I'm not gonna post publically, it returns this.

```
<p>Example text <a href="example">Example</a> more example <a href="second example">Second example</a></p>
```

How would I remove the `<p>` and `<a href="">` tags? And any other tags lurking about?

Answer (score 0):

Most `bs4` tags have a `.strings` attribute that is a generator for all strings in the tag.

```
print(''.join(final.strings))
# Example text Example more example Second example
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you checking for the html tags using regex and replacing them with empty string .

reg = r'\<\*[^>]+>' . This seems to be working .

Comment: "Using a regular expression to parse HTML is fraught with pitfalls." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags