# Linux Bash Regex on a HTML table get one row

Tags: html, regex, bash, sed, grep

```
result=$(
wget -qO- 'http://www.kuchenpeter.at/mittagsmenue.html' |
sed -n '/<p>/,/<\/p>/p'
)
echo $result
```

I try to get the menu from this [page](http://kuchenpeter.at/mittagsmenue.html).

So i need 5 strings from the table [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpGhg.jpg)

The bad thing on this page is when you look at the html code below they really messed up the tags.

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #888;" valign="top">
    <p>
        <strong>
            <span style="font-size: 12px;">
                Puszta-Kotelett mit Pommes-frites
            </span>
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">
            &nbsp;
        </span>
    </p>
</td>
###########################################
<td style="text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #888;" valign="top">
    <p>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">
            <strong>
                Hühnergeschnetzeltes "Asia" mit Reis
            </strong>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;
    </p>
</td>   
###########################################
<td style="text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #888;" valign="top">
    <p>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">
            <strong>
                <span style="font-size: 12px;">
                    <strong>
                        Tafelspitz mit Apfelkren, Schnittlauchsauce und Röstinchen
                    </strong>
                </span>
            </strong>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;
    </p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #888;" valign="top">
    <p>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">
            <strong>
                Puten-Picatta "Milanese" mit Salat
            </strong>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;" valign="top">
    <p>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">
            <strong>
                Gebratener Dorsch mit Gemüse und Petersilkartoffeln
            </strong>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">
            &nbsp;
        </span>
    </p>
</td>
```

Comment: You should use an HTML parser and make queries with e.g. XPath instead of using regex.

Comment: In your case, You need to strip the html tags; then it will be easy to extract the information you need. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string) to know how to remove html tag using regex

Comment: This is the answer you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1705337

Answer (score 2):

My [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) can do it with pattern matching, which almost looks like a regex.

Everything in the row after "Tagessuppe":

```
xidel http://www.kuchenpeter.at/mittagsmenue.html -e "<tr>Tagessuppe</tr><tr><strong>{.}</strong>+</tr>"
```

Or in the third row:

```
xidel http://www.kuchenpeter.at/mittagsmenue.html -e "<div class="block"><tr/>{2}<tr><strong>{.}</strong>+</tr></div>"
```

Comment: Using XPath: `xidel file.html -q --xpath '//table/tbody/tr[3]/td/p[1]//text()'`

Comment: Thank you BeniBela and Casimir et Hippolyte Xidel is realy the best tool I have ever seen to do that =)
I used it like this now:
`result1=$(xidel http://www.kuchenpeter.at/mittagsmenue.html  --xpath '//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/p[1]//text()')`

For mor behind information I will use this to send me the menu of the week via a telegram bot =)