# How to extract WikiTables from Wikipedia page by API?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to extract every textual content from a Wikipedia Page including the tables using API sandbox for the Wikipedia page on [Ballon_d'Or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballon_d'Or).

I tried the given query:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=Ballon_d%27Or&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=wiki
```

but it provides me only the textual content without the content from the wiki table like this one:

[image]

Is there a way I could obtain the table content in a textual format along with the textual information already being obtained?

Alternatively, I can try the web crawling technique using beautiful Soup but I wanted to look for the query method, first.

Comment: Nope, you'll have to use some kind of HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Use `action`=[`parse`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) instead [`query`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Ballon_d'Or&prop=text
```

By using [`&section=2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Ballon_d%27Or&prop=text&section=2) you will access the second section [Winners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballon_d'Or#Winners).

This maybe will help you later also: [Regular expression to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags)