# How to wrap first word in a string without wrapping the HTML elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to wrap the first word in a string, for example:

```
var html = '<br> <br> Hello world!';
```

I have the following code:

```
html.replace(/^\s*\w+/, '<div class="underline">$&</div>');
```

This will output:

```
<div class="underline"><br></div> <br> Hello world!
```

How can I ignore HTML tags so that the output is like this, where the first word "Hello" gets wrapped in the DIV?:

```
<br> <br> <div class="underline">Hello</div> world!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DOMParser to create a document from the string, then [look through text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes) in the document to find one whose trimmed text is not the empty string. Replace that node with a `<div class="underline">`:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes
const getTextNodes = (parent) => {
    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        parent,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        null,
        false
    );

    let node;
    const nodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        nodes.push(node);
    }
    return nodes;
};

const html = '<br> <br> Hello world!';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
const nodes = getTextNodes(doc.body);
const node = nodes.find(node => node.textContent.trim() !== '');
const [, firstWord, rest] = node.textContent.match(/(\S+)(.*)/);
const newNode = document.createElement('div');
newNode.className = 'underline';
newNode.textContent = firstWord;
node.replaceWith(newNode);
newNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', rest);
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Your result is wrapping "Hello world!".  I want it just to wrap the first word "Hello".

Comment: Ah, that's right, need to split off the first `\S+` from the rest first

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
html.replace(/[^< ][A-Za-z]+[^> ]/, '<div class="underline">$&</div>');
```

or

```
html.replace(/([^< ][A-Za-z]+[^> ])/, '<div class="underline">$1</div>');
```

For reference, the same function in sed command is

```
echo '<br> <br> Hello world!' | sed -e 's/\([^< ][A-Za-z]\+[^> ]\)/<div class="underline">\1<\/div>/'
```

To support single body character,

```
html.replace(/([^<][A-Za-z]+[^>])/, '<div class="underline">$1</div>');
```

Although, if the html tag has some attributes like `<p class="classname">`, it won't work. DOMParser will be necessary instead of regex or, consult [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags).

Comment: This is not working for words with 1 or 2 characters, such as "a", "or", "we", "us" etc.

Comment: ok, two more minor issues.  The reg replace is removing a space at the end of the word being wrapped, and it's not working for single-character words, such as "a" or "I".  It is, however, working for two-character words, such as "no", "at", "hi", etc.