# Regex expression to remove HTML tags And \r and \n tags

Tags: html, regex

I have a strings like

```
'{\"name\":\"[\\\"Uses\\\",\\\"Tags\\\"]\",\"value\":\"[\\\"<table border=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellpadding=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellspacing=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"299\\\\\\\" xss=removed><tbody><tr height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" xss=removed>\\\\r\\\\n  <td height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" class=\\\\\\\"xl66\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"299\\\\\\\" xss=removed>A\\\\r\\\\n  cleaning product, A repair service, A fashion brand, A personal shopper, An\\\\r\\\\n  app,<\\\\\\/td><\\\\\\/tr><\\\\\\/tbody><\\\\\\/table>\\\",\\\"<table border=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellpadding=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellspacing=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"232\\\\\\\" xss=removed><tbody><tr height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" xss=removed>\\\\r\\\\n  <td height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" class=\\\\\\\"xl66\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"232\\\\\\\" xss=removed>Apparel,\\\\r\\\\n  Charity & Nonprofit , Fashion, Operations, Products, Retail &\\\\r\\\\n  eCommerce<\\\\\\/td><\\\\\\/tr><\\\\\\/tbody><\\\\\\/table>\\\"]\"}'
```

I want to remove html tags. I tried :

```
<[^>]*>|\\|(u00a0*.)
```

It removes most of it but

```
\\r\\\\n
```

still remains. please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags)

Comment: This looks like HTML in an array of a JSON field, which in turn is in a JSON field of a JSON string (phew!). Recommended approach: 1. Parse the JSON; 2. Get the "value" field, which is a stringified JSON array; 3. Parse that JSON to get the array of strings; 4. Iterate over the array of strings, where each string is HTML; 4. Parse the HTML to extract plain text. Alternative to 4, strip HTML from string using regex.

Comment: If you are ok with a not so robust solution you could use a regex or several regexes to extract the plain text. What language do you use?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @PeterThoeny python

Comment: @MaciejLos I want to convert it into json object like Peter Thoeny said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = '{\"name\":\"[\\\"Uses\\\",\\\"Tags\\\"]\",\"value\":\"[\\\"<table border=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellpadding=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellspacing=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"299\\\\\\\" xss=removed><tbody><tr height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" xss=removed>\\\\r\\\\n  <td height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" class=\\\\\\\"xl66\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"299\\\\\\\" xss=removed>A\\\\r\\\\n  cleaning product, A repair service, A fashion brand, A personal shopper, An\\\\r\\\\n  app,<\\\\\\/td><\\\\\\/tr><\\\\\\/tbody><\\\\\\/table>\\\",\\\"<table border=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellpadding=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" cellspacing=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"232\\\\\\\" xss=removed><tbody><tr height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" xss=removed>\\\\r\\\\n  <td height=\\\\\\\"60\\\\\\\" class=\\\\\\\"xl66\\\\\\\" width=\\\\\\\"232\\\\\\\" xss=removed>Apparel,\\\\r\\\\n  Charity & Nonprofit , Fashion, Operations, Products, Retail &\\\\r\\\\n  eCommerce<\\\\\\/td><\\\\\\/tr><\\\\\\/tbody><\\\\\\/table>\\\"]\"}'
string = string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)|\\r|\\n/ig,"")
```

Comment: Thank u so much @Harney.