# Firebase rule to prevent HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase realtime database which allows users to post comments which are then displayed to other users.

Is there a way to add a rule to validate that no HTML tags are being submitted? For example:

```
This is my <b>comment</b> which I <text style="color:red;">have edited</text>
```

Now I know I can do this using javascript on the users end to check, but I need to add the text as .html() and not .text() so I think it would be better to also do it via a firebase rule.

Is this possible?

Comment: Performing this check in client-side JS is almost pointless as it's so easy to workaround. You need to sanitise the inputs on the server side.

Comment: Which database are you using? The syntax differs between the RTDB and Firestore.

Comment: @samthecodingman realtime database

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a trivial language and parsing HTML using regular expressions is often advised against like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11229831/3068190) and its [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790681/3068190).

However as you are just using it to test for the presence of HTML-like tags and not for parsing, you could just test against the regular expression `/<[^>]*>/`.

Assuming you have a message data structure similar to this:

```js
interface MessageData {
  author: string,
  content: string,
  /* ... */
}
```

and store them in your database as `/messages/someMessageId`, you could use a [`.validate` rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#validate) to apply the test using [`rules.String#matches()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#matchesregex):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$msgId": {
        "content": {
          // a message must be a string and not contain any HTML-like tags
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && !newData.val().matches(/<[^>]*>/)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** An alternative to this is to post the message using a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that sanitizes it prior to adding it to the database or [trigger a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) in response to messages posted and sanitize the message afterwards. Either method would allow a secure way to perform a more in-depth analysis of the input.