# Html.Table Equivalent in Power query Using Regex

Tags: excel, powerquery

So Power Query doesn't have the Html.Table Function that can be found in Power BI.

So can we use regex to convert Html into text and make an equivalent function?

Previous posts state that this shouldn't be done since HTML doesn't follow the same rules as text, however .. needs must. Its also just interesting as a question and if achievable, would prove very useful for scraping difficult pages, directly in excel.

I came across this regex:

https://regex101.com/r/AtElMH/2 From and answer on the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags). Seems to work reasonably well.

So Im wondering if I can use this to tidy up any HTML that I pull into excel from the web connector. Each line from the table in blue comes from submitting the HTML to https://www.textfixer.com/html/html-to-text.php just to give an idea of what each row should expect. However, as per the Regex 101 link it does not have to be perfect i.e. if the occasional tag slips through, that's okay; it's more of a tidy-up. I would rather that than a pattern that loses data.

[image]

Currently, submitting this regex into FnRegexReplace Function results in an error. I don't know if the regex can be read correctly by excel and, if not, if there are any work arounds.

**FnRegexReplace:** Note: `y = Text.Replace(y,"\","\\")`, so no need for `\\`

```
(x,y,z)=>
let 
   
   y = Text.Replace(y,"\","\\"),
   
   Source = Web.Page(
                     "<script>var x="&"'"&x&"'"&";var z="&"'"&z&
                     "'"&";var y=new RegExp('"&y&"','gmi');
                     var b=x.replace(y,z);document.write(b);</script>")
                     [Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}
in 
   Source
```

**M Code:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "FnRegexReplace", each FnRegexReplace([Column1], "<([\w\-\/]+)( +[\w\-]+(=(('[^']*')|(""[^""]*"")))?)* *>", " "))
in
    #"Invoked Custom Function"
```

**HTML DATA:**

```
    </div><!-- SectionHeaderWrapper --><div id="SectionContent"><h3 id="sAdministrativeDataSummary" class="mDisabled">Administrative data</h3><h3 id="sWorkersHazardViaInhalationRoute">Workers - Hazard via inhalation route</h3><h4>Systemic effects</h4><h5>Long term exposure</h5><dl class="HorDL"><dt>Hazard assessment conclusion:</dt><dd>no hazard identified</dd></dl></dl></dl></dl></dl></dl><h5>Acute/short term exposure</h5><dl class="HorDL"><dt>Hazard assessment conclusion:</dt><dd>no hazard identified</dd></dl><h6>DNEL related information</h6></dl></dl></dl></dl></dl><h4>Local effects</h4><h5>Long term exposure</h5><dl class="HorDL"><dt>Hazard assessment conclusion:</dt><dd>DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
Value:</dt><dd><span class="UserEntry">0.02</span> mg/m&sup3;
Most sensitive endpoint:</dt><dd>repeated dose toxicity</dd></dl><h6>DNEL related information</h6><dl class="HorDL"><dt>DNEL derivation method:</dt><dd>other: <span class="UserEntry">Biocidal Products Regulation guidance for Human Health Risk Assessment (Volume III, Part B, December 2013</span>
Overall assessment factor (AF):</dt><dd class="UserEntry">16
Dose descriptor:</dt><dd>NOAEC
Value:</dt><dd><span class="UserEntry">0.34</span> mg/m&sup3;
AF for dose response relationship:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">1
Justification:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">NOAEC defined based on local effects of irritation/corrosion which are considered concentration dependent
AF for differences in duration of exposure:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">2
Justification:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">NOAEC derived from subchronic study therefore extrapolating to chronic duration
AF for interspecies differences (allometric scaling):</dt><dd class="UserEntry">2.5
Justification:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">Local effects observed only therefore toxicokinetics do not contribute to interspecies differences
AF for other interspecies differences:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">1
Justification:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">Local effects observed only therefore toxicokinetics do not contribute to interspecies differences
AF for intraspecies differences:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">3.2
Justification:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">Local effects observed only therefore toxicokinetics do not contribute to intraspecies differences
AF for the quality of the whole database:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">1
Justification:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">Hazards well characterised in multiple studies of good reliability 
AF for remaining uncertainties:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">1
Justification:</dt><dd class="UserEntry">No remaining uncertainties</dd></dl></dl></dl></dl></dl><h5>Acute/short term exposure</h5><dl class="HorDL"><dt>Hazard assessment conclusion:</dt><dd>DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer so Far: `(<[^<>]*>)+` however I am not sure how well this works for other HTML text using "___" as substitution

Answer (score 1):

For fun, not using recursion or regex

```
//single column of HTML text as input into [Column1]
// removes all text betweeen all pairs of < and >
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\a.txt")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.ToList([Column1])),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom"),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Custom.1", each if [Custom]="<" or [Custom]=">" then [Custom] else null),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1", "Custom.1 - Copy"),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Duplicated Column",{"Custom.1 - Copy"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([#"Custom.1 - Copy"] = ">") and ([Custom.1] = null)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column1", "Custom.1", "Custom.1 - Copy"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Index"}, {{"data", each Text.Combine(_[Custom]), type text}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

then you'd probably go back and replace all HTML entities like

> Entities

```
&amp;
&sup3;
```