# Regex to grab validate email address in complete XML string or normal string

Tags: java, regex

Need to grab string text of email value in big XML/normal string.

Been working with Regex for it and as of now below Regex is working correctly for normal String
Regex : `` ^[\\w!#$%&amp;'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[\\w!#$%&amp;'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1,6}$ ``

Text : `paris@france.c`

but in case when above text is enclosed in XML tag it fails to return.
`<email>paris@france.c</email>`

I am trying to amend some change to this regex so that it will work for both of the scenarios

Comment: change `^` to `(^|>)` and `$` to `($|<)`

Comment: you could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24350326/16034206) which trims html tags so that you get regular strings then you can apply the regular regex. You would of course need to apply some logic to trim the XML tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have put `^` at the beginning which means the "Start of the string", and `$` at the end which means the "End of the string". Now, look at your string:

```
<email>paris@france.c</email>
```

Do you think, it starts and ends with an email address?

I have removed them and also escaped the `-` in your regex. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/XrJmBN/1/codegen?language=java) you can check the following auto-generated Java code with the updated regex.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "[\\w!#$%&amp;'*+/=?`\\{|\\}~^\\-]+(?:\\\\.[\\w!#$%&amp;'*+/=?`\\{|\\}~^\\-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1,6}";
        final String string = "paris@france.c\n"
     + "<email>paris@france.c</email>";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Full match: paris@france.c
Full match: paris@france.c
```